# Doubtful that vs doubtful whether/if

Tags: grammaticality

Objective Proficiency 2013 Workbook, Unit 7 UOE

In view of his appalling behavior, it's doubtful whether/if Geoff will be invited to the wedding.

Why whether/if but not "that"? I don't mind whether/if though. I looked everywhere, so far no luck.

Comment: Who says you can't use _that_? Of course, you can't use it if you use _whether_ or _if_, but you can if you don't. _Doubt(ful)_ means there is only possibility, which allows _if_, but _doubt(ful)_ also takes tensed complements with _that_.

Comment: 'Doubtful that ...' comes across as conveying more unlikeliness than 'doubtful whether ..' to my ears. Possibly a fairly subjective-end-of-the-spectrum connotation.

Comment: Thank you, John, that's what I thought. But I checked the correct answer in the CPE Workbook and acc to Cambridge the correct answer is whether/if.

Comment: Thank you, Edwin. Longman makes a subtle point about that though not explicitly. I wouldn’t use “that” in the sentence 2. The problem is I’m still not sure why; the difference is minute.

1 probably not true or not likely to happen  [ is doubtful if/whether It was doubtful whether the patient would survive the operation.]  [it is doubtful that It is doubtful that the missing airmen will ever be found.]
2 not sure that something is true or right [doubtful if/whether I’m still doubtful whether I should accept this job.]
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/doubtful